# How to pass parameters into a function before calling it

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am creating a page where people can click on various links and it will pass lat/lng data into a Google Maps API initialization function, but I can't figure out how to pass the parameters into the function.

I found a similar question with an answer that suggested using `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass parameters into the callback before it's called, but I'm not sure I understand how that works because currently I am getting `gmapsInit is not a function`

Here's my code:

```js
function initMap(lat, lng) {
 return function() {
  var loc = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
  console.log(loc);
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        position: loc,
        pov: {
          heading: 10,
          pitch: 10
        },
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        motionTracking: true
      });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
 }
}

$(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lat')),
  lng = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lng'));
        
    // Here's what I tried
    var gmapsInit = initMap.bind(null, lat, lng);
        
    $('.result').append('<div id="map"></div><script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=gmapsInit"></script>');
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-lat="48.8584" data-lng="2.2945">

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is currying that you want ?

Comment: Other than bind, more readable solution is just create a new function: `var gmapsInit = function() { return initMap(lat, lng) }`

Comment: The problem is that the scope of the `gmapsInit` variable is limited, try `window.gmapsInit = initMap.bind(null, lat, lng);`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need bind, just make sure your `callback` is available globally.

```
var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lat')),
    lng = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lng'));

window.gmapsInit = function(){
    initMap(lat, lng)();
}
 $('.result').append( //...
```